# Integers multipled by a natural number must be between 0 and n-1?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given that $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n\geq 2$ and $r\in\mathbb R$

For every $j\in\mathbb N$ there exists an integer $x_{j}\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\frac{x_{j}}{n^{j}}\leq r <\frac{x_{j}+1}{n^{j}}$

Is it true that this implies that $x_{j+1}-x_{j}\cdot n$ must be between $0$ and $n-1$?

My professor claimed this in the notes but I can’t seem to understand why this must hold true?

Comment: Is it really $\frac {x_j}{n^j}$ and not $\frac {x_j}{n_j}$?  In which case, I am not sure why $j$ is even relevant to the proposition.

Comment: Find double inequality for $x_j$ from definition of $x_j$, then use it for $j=j+1$ to find double inequality for $x_{j+1}$, then manipulate to find double inequality for $x_{j+1}-nx_j$. You will get something like $-1 < x_{j+1}-n x_j < n$. $x_{j+1}-n x_j$ is integer then $0\leq x_{j+1}-n x_j \leq n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$x_{j+1}\le n^{j+1}r<x_{j+1}+1$$
and
$$x_j\le n^jr<x_j+1.$$
Multiplying the second line by $-n$ gives
$$-nx_j-n<-^{j+1}r\le-nx_j.$$
Adding this termwise to the first line, we obtain:
$$x_{j+1}-nx_j-n<0<x_{j+1}+1-nx_j,$$
i.e.
$$-1<x_{j+1}-nx_j<n,$$
q.e.d.